# Getting efficiently the Genres of the Audio files in the MediaStore

Tags: android, audio, mediastore

I am trying to synchronize my own database for tracks and albums (that contains additional data). I have so far successfully pulled albums and tracks from the MediaStore.

What I cannot manage to do properly is to pull the Genres for the tracks. Could someone post some code? I'd like to avoid querying the database for each track, so if possible some code to load the association (Genre.id <-> Audio.id) would be great.

What I am struggling on is using the content provider to get the Genres.Members info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take a look at how the excellent creators of ringdroid do this. http://ringdroid.googlecode.com/svn-history/r37/trunk/src/com/ringdroid/SongMetadataReader.java

They basically start by retrieving the genres names and ids and using those they can easily create a content_uri that retrieves only songs in the database that matches those genres. 
But if I were you I would check whether there is an "unknown" or "empty" genre or not for the files that contain no Genre name in their id3 tag

Comment: Thanks, I had found that link but however it is rather inefficient as what I want is to avoid making a request for each song to get the genre. So I would need to get a list of all the associations (audio_id, genre_id), if possible limit the number of genre_id to 1 per audio_id (the first one for instance) so that I can cache a HashMap of those.

Comment: This actually does not make a request for each song. Rather a request per genre. So if you have 2 genres {rock, classic} then only two db requests (queries) are made.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a closer look at it.

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing is getting all audio files on the sd with a loader and following query:

```
        loader = new CursorLoader(mActivity, MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                new String[] {Audio.Media._ID, Audio.Media.DATA}, 
                null, null, null);
```

Then i check if they end with .mp3 and I then use [jaudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/) and read the ide3 tags for genre.