# Android Mediastore: How to efficiently retrieve all songs of a certain genre?

Tags: android, mediastore

I know how to retrieve the genre of a particular song, (see [getting the genres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889242/getting-efficiently-the-genres-of-the-audio-files-in-the-mediastore)), but I want to retrieve all songs of a particular genre. Since "genre" does not seem to be one of the columns for a media item, I don't know how to do it in a single query, unlike artist or album. Is there an efficient method? Thanx!

Comment: Unless the list of music is monstrous (30k songs+), I don't think you will suffer to much of a performance penalty by just getting all the songs, then checking there genre and adding the correct one to a list.

Comment: I have 2K songs, and it takes long enough to want to put up a progress dialog, even on my moderately fast Samsung Charge. It is very slow on my 600MHz cheapo tablet (for some reason, more than twice as slow). That's what I'll do if required, but I was hoping there was a trick I'm missing.

Answer (score 15):

```
Uri uri = Audio.Genres.Members.getContentUri("external", genreID); 

String[] projection = new String[]{Audio.Media.TITLE, Audio.Media._ID};

Cursor cur = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Could you add some text explaining what you've done here perhaps?

Comment: Audio.Genres.Members.getContentUri("external", genreID) makes uri, like (content://media/external/audio/genres/2/members) where "external" means, that we will search through external content, and "2" is genre ID. ContentResolver.query(...) query the given uri and returns a Cursor over the result set.

Comment: @AlexanderMikhalevich can u please help me for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235127/cleanest-method-to-play-songs-from-album-artist-genre-in-android

Comment: the link is not available @AkshayMukadam

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by putting together a content URI and querying the MediaStore. Here's some code borrowed from the Android music player:

```
String [] cols = new String [] {MediaStore.Audio.Genres.NAME};
Cursor cursor = MusicUtils.query(this,
                ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Genres.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, Long.valueOf(mGenre)),
                cols, null, null, null);
```

This is the code in MusicUtils:

```
public static Cursor query(Context context, Uri uri, String[] projection,
        String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder, int limit) {
    try {
        ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        if (resolver == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (limit > 0) {
            uri = uri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("limit", "" + limit).build();
        }
        return resolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
     } catch (UnsupportedOperationException ex) {
        ErrorReporter.getInstance().putCustomData("UnsupportedOperationException", "true");
        return null;
    }

}
```